# How can I send data to remote components when building components in shell?

Tags: webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

In the following example:

https://github.com/manfredsteyer/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer

how can I send data to remote components when building components in shell?

```
async loadWidget() {
    this.viewContainer.clear()

    const Component = await loadRemoteModule(this.widgets[0]).then(m => m[this.widgets[0].componentName])

    this.viewContainer.createComponent(Component)
}
```